# Django 1.9 ImportError for import_module

Tags: python, django, django-1.9

When trying to run either `runserver` or `shell` using `manage.py` I get an `ImportError` exception. I'm using Django 1.9.

```
ImportError: No module named 'django.utils.importlib'
```

Comment: Note that Django 1.9 has only just reached alpha status, and is not suitable for production use. Use 1.8 unless you have a very good reason.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I'm only running it in local development at the moment, it's more of a means to help the Django team track down issues that would hold back a stable release.

Comment: Django 1.9 is out now.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

`django.utils.importlib` is a compatibility library for when Python 2.6 was still supported. It has been obsolete since Django 1.7, which dropped support for Python 2.6, and is removed in 1.9 per the deprecation cycle.

Use Python's `import_module` function instead:

```
from importlib import import_module
```

The reason you can import it from `django.utils.module_loading` is that `importlib.import_module` is imported in that module, it is *not* because `module_loading` in any way defines the actual function.

Since `django.utils.module_loading.import_module` is not part of the public API, it can be removed at any time if it is no longer used - even in a minor version upgrade.

Answer (score 20):

I solved this with the following:

```py
try:
    # Django versions >= 1.9
    from django.utils.module_loading import import_module
except ImportError:
    # Django versions < 1.9
    from django.utils.importlib import import_module
```

Comment: In which file can i write this code? I updated my django from 1.7 to 1.9. And stopped work.

Comment: looks like a bug in endless_pagination or similar

Comment: Thank you. I installed django-request to monitor traffic. I made the change you suggested in plugins.py and traffic.py and all is well now.

Comment: Hi I just want to ask while file should I write this code?

Comment: a safer solution for me