# edx Django RemovedInDjango19Warning

Tags: django, django-models, edx, openedx

I got into an error with django in open edx on RemovedInDjango19Warning. I wonder if anyone knows how to fix them?

```
2016-01-18 17:58:04,541 WARNING 3543 [py.warnings] base.py:116 - /edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth_provider/models.py:73: RemovedInDjango19Warning: Model class oauth_provider.models.Token doesn't declare an explicit app_label and either isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS or else was imported before its application was loaded. This will no longer be supported in Django 1.9.
  class Token(models.Model):

/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/require/helpers.py:4: RemovedInDjango19Warning: django.utils.importlib will be removed in Django 1.9.
  from django.utils.importlib import import_module

2016-01-18 17:58:11,199 WARNING 3543 [py.warnings] importlib.py:9 - /edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/require/helpers.py:4: RemovedInDjango19Warning: django.utils.importlib will be removed in Django 1.9.
  from django.utils.importlib import import_module
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django 1.9 ImportError for import\_module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32761566/django-1-9-importerror-for-import-module)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are only warnings, you can ignore them for now.  We'll clean up the code to prevent them.

Open edX moved from Django 1.4 to Django 1.8 recently.  Upgrading your installation is not a simple matter.  We'll be able to support you better on the mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/edx-code

Comment: Hi, I tried to ask the same question on the edx forum but receive no answer at all

Comment: then those django comment can be ignore also? `2016-02-03 16:19:23,985 WARNING 24984 [py.warnings] base.py:116 - /edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/lms/djangoapps/instructor_task/models.py:39: RemovedInDjango19Warning: Model class instructor_task.models.InstructorTask doesn't declare an explicit app_label and either isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS or else was imported before its application was loaded. This will no longer be supported in Django 1.9.`

Comment: Yes, ignore those warnings.