# Cannot import importlib

Tags: python, django, listfield, python-importlib

I am trying to use Listfield from djangotoolbox.fields but it is giving me an error saying :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
autoreload.raise_last_exception()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 249, in raise_last_exception
six.reraise(*_exception)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
app_config.import_models(all_models)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
File "/Users/coderahul/Desktop/Experiment Box/Innovation/Codeplay/codeplay/data_aggregator/models.py", line 9, in <module>
from djangotoolbox.fields import ListField
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/djangotoolbox/fields.py", line 4, in <module>
from django.utils.importlib import import_module
ImportError: No module named importlib
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import a module in Python with importlib.import\_module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10675054/how-to-import-a-module-in-python-with-importlib-import-module)

Comment: Importlib is not a Django util, it's in the Python standard. Just `from importlib import import_module`.

Answer (score 2):

> django.utils.importlib is a compatibility library for when Python 2.6
>   was still supported. It has been obsolete since Django 1.7, which
>   dropped support for Python 2.6, and is removed in 1.9 per the
>   deprecation cycle.

Try this

```
from importlib import import_module
```

source [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32761566/django-1-9-importerror-for-import-module)

Comment: Where should I add this? In models?

Comment: I favour  you to use django-1.9 for djangotoolbox otherwise use NoSQL database if you want Listfield .

Comment: bcoz djangotoolbox is not maintained and well documented.

Answer (score 0):

use `from importlib import import_module`