# Django-Bleach or Just Bleach?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-templates

I've recently tried to implement Django-Bleach into my project, but I'm having an issue with an import library.  I am currently running Python 3.6.2 and Django 1.11.  When I try to define a django_bleach form in my forms.py, with the following statement:

```
from django_bleach.forms import BleachField
```

I am receiving the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.utils.importlib'
```

I spent the better part of this afternoon researching this error and I have come to understand that the django.utils.importlib statement was deprecated in 1.9.    However, I can't seem to determine a workaround for this problem.  I did try the suggestion outlined in this issue but it didn't seem to make a difference.  I still receive the error.  [Cannot import importlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41997496/cannot-import-importlib)

I'm also wondering if I should be using bleach instead of django-bleach as django-bleach doesn't seem to be updated since 2014.  Thanks in advance for your suggestions and help.

Comment: please you can check this, I think it would help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/32763639/9970044

Comment: Bilal Mahmud Thanks for the suggestion.  I saw it as well but to no aval.  Where would the code that was outlined at the bottom of the issue...try:
    # Django versions >= 1.9
    from django.utils.module_loading import import_module
except ImportError:
    # Django versions < 1.9
    from django.utils.importlib import import_module  Be placed?  I put it in my forms.py file and it still did not help.  I also tried to add from importlib import import_module to my forms.py file and that did not help either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Package you are trying to use doesen't seem to be maintained.

Error you are facing is related to the [forms.py](https://bitbucket.org/tim_heap/django-bleach/src/58d17e3ea8966ded000a7a3be55867fe03c890aa/django_bleach/forms.py#lines-7) line 7

```
from django.utils.importlib import import_module
```

If you are really into the following wrapper package you could fork/fix it and install your forked version instead

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately wound up incorporating just bleach into my django installation.  It appears django-bleach is no longer supported for Python 3.  Using Bleach and incorporating it according to the documentation allowed me resolve this issue.

Comment: `django-bleach` has since been updated with support for python 3 and django 2.x - https://pypi.org/project/django-bleach/